# How do I create a Foreign Key in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two db classes defined as shown below

```
[Table("Warehouses")]
public class Warehouse : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual WarehouseAddress Address { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FKWarehouseAddressId")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
[Table("Customers")]
public class Customer : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Warehouse Warehouse { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FK_WarehouseId")]
    public int WarehouseId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual DistributionRoute DistributionRoute { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FKRouteId")]
    public int RouteId { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerAddress CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FKAddressId")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is for every record in Customers table to have a WarehouseId column which refers to the Id column in Warehouses table. I ama not sure where I am getting it wrong because for the RouteId column which is in DistributionRoute table it works fine. Can someone help. When I try to update my database I am getting the error below:

*The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Customers_Warehouses_WarehouseId". The conflict occurred in database "StoreDb", table "dbo.Warehouses", column 'Id'.*

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix the classes, I don't know what another properties for.  I can only guess that you don't need some of them, so I show only properties that you need to create one-to-many betwee warehouse and customer

```
[Table("Warehouses")]
public class Warehouse : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    .....
     [InverseProperty(nameof(Customer.Warehouse))]
     public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

[Table("Customers")]
public class Customer : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{

    ......
   
    public int? WarehouseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(WarehouseId))]
    [InverseProperty("Customers")]
    public virtual Warehouse Warehouse { get; set; }
}
```

you have to clean your classes. Add to this properties only properties that exist in your database. After this you have to make a  Db migration.

Comment: Just tried this and I am getting same error

Comment: @MutongiGava Ok , i didn't know that your db is existing. I changed  public int WarehouseId  to int? . Try it again. If it doesn' t work you will have to create a new db